# Getting a ClassCastException when trying a join query in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, classcastexception

This is my tables:

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="Students")
public class Students {

```
@Id
@Column(name="Student_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="Student_Name")
private String name;

@Column(name="Email_ID")
private String emailId;

@Column(name="Phone_no")
private long phoneNo;

@Column(name="Class_ID")
private int classId;

@Column(name="DOB")
private Date dob;
```

and

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="Assigned")
public class Assign {

```
@Id
@Column(name="Assign_ID")
private int aId;

@Column(name="Class_ID")
private int classId;

@Column(name="Teacher_ID")
private int tId;

@Column(name="Subject_ID")
private int sId;
```

When I run this code :

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.append("<html><body>");

    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    Session session = sf.openSession();
    
    List<Subjects> subjects = session.createQuery(" from Subjects").list();
    
    out.println("<h1> Students List :-");
    out.println("<table>");
    
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<th> Subject Id </th>");
    out.println("<th> Subject Name </th>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    
    for(Subjects subject : subjects ) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>"+subject.getsId()+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+subject.getsName()+"</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    out.append("</body></html>");
```

It works just fine But when I try to run this:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.append("<html><body>");

    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    Session session = sf.openSession();
    
    List<Subjects> subjects = session.createQuery("from Subjects s, Assign a where s.sId = a.sId and a.classId = 2").list();
    
    out.println("<h1> Students List :-");
    out.println("<table>");
    
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<th> Subject Id </th>");
    out.println("<th> Subject Name </th>");
    out.println("</tr>");
    
    for(Subjects subject : subjects ) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>"+subject.getsId()+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+subject.getsName()+"</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    out.append("</body></html>");
```

it gives this error :
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class entity.Subjects ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; entity.Subjects is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @7aeb7c5e)

I didn't do @Manytoone Annotation as I read here( [How to make this select * from two joined tables query in HQL form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677203/how-to-make-this-select-from-two-joined-tables-query-in-hql-form)) you can also work without them.

I have tried various things but to no avail. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explicit cast is needed, so use the code below instead:

```
List<Subjects> subjects = 
session.createQuery(
          "select s from Subjects s, Assign a where s.sId = a.sId and 
           a.classId = 2", Subjects.class).list();
```